# Can not open vscode which install via anaconda in terminal on macOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

run `code` in terminal

```
zsh: command not found: code
```

But, it is normal in launchpad. May be a problem with environment variables, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: try typing 'which code' at the terminal and show the result in a comment here.

Answer (score 4):

Press Command+Shift+P, type “install code” and select the highlighted option.

[image]